# Defining fish shell as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, fish

After sets fish as default bash by `chsh -s "which fish"`

/usr/bin/rails **or**
rails outputs:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
    $ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

and more strange behaivor when `which rvm` it's outputs nothing, whereas bash works fine.

And earlier when I ran fish manualy it's works fine too.
What happened and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

> Since RVM is a large collection of bash scripts and fish is not
>   bash-compatible, users of fish need a wrapper around RVM to make it
>   work properly with that shell. Since RVM just manipulates environment
>   variables, we just need a way to preserve those changes.

Download the fish functions from GitHub.

```
curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

And activate the default Ruby manually in your config.fish file:

```
echo "rvm default" >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

http://rvm.io/integration/fish

or you can try [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish) with the [rvm-plugin](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-rvm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it do not solve main question about strange output when I run rails or rake. I think it something about $PATH

Answer (score 0):

Setting your default shell to fish with

```
chsh -s "which fish"
```

is not a very good idea, since many programs assume you have a POSIX compliant shell linked to sh

An alternative way to start fish on login is add this to your .bashrc

```
exec fish
```

Another way is setting the default shell in your terminal emulator

More info on this:
[fish article on arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fish)